# Can't call php script from PDF

Tags: php, forms, pdf, submit

I've setup my php script and posted it on my site's root directory. I can call this from within an html form, which sends my form data to it for submission to SalesForce. This works great - it creates a new Lead.

The problem is, I need to send this form data from a PDF file, and when I try to submit my data from Acrobat (HTML Format), I get a "Cannot Connect To Server" error. Submitting from Acrobat Reader, I get `An error occurred during the submit process. Cannot process content of type text/html; charset=UTF-8.`

Using mailto: from the PDF, I can see that I'm just sending a pure html string:

```
city=Aspen&company=CORE&email=marty%40aspencore.org&first_name=Trina&last_name=Ortega&oid=00DA0000000XXXX&retURL=www.energysmartcolorado.com&state=CO&Submit=
```

I'm not a programmer, so please go easy on me with any replies. Thanks!

Comment: Acrobat reader is complaining it can't do anything with the _reply_ from the server. You need to find out what it expects, because apparently HTML isn't it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Francis! I do get the script to work from other html calls, just not from the PDF, so I think the server is expecting html?

Comment: @MartyTreadway there is a reasonable chance that the PDF is expecting a particular format in response. Your PDF isn't HTML.

Comment: @leemachin, I am trying both the built-in submit button that Acrobat supplies, and a custom javascript to mimic the submit:  var url="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8";
this.submitForm(url, true); They are both receiving this same cannot connect error...

Comment: Sorry - here's my simple javascript to submit the form: var url="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8"
this.submitForm(url, true);

Comment: Marty, I think you still misunderstand. Acrobat is (probably) *sending* the request *to the server* successfully, but the server *replies* back to Acrobat (or a browser, or whatever) in HTML, and Acrobat Reader doesn't know what to do with HTML replies. Hence the error "Cannot process content of type text/html; charset=UTF-8," which is about the *reply*, not the stuff you *send*. Acrobat Reader is probably expecting the reply to be in a different format.

Answer (score 0):

We uninstalled adobe reader and re installed the Latest version of Adobe reader.

Post Installation of new version when we click on the print option we are getting pop up to allow the access to create Temp file in C:\

Which will allowed by clicking on allow button.